# Creating One-to-Many with Relationship for the ORM in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am learning SQLAlchemy and I've read a lot on relationships today including more than a few posts on SO. However, none of the examples I've found quite answer this question even though I would think it would be one of the first to be answered when dealing with relationships.

I have webpage form data and a lot of it is repetitive - like the the visitors Browser User Agent string, Domain the form was served on and Domain it was served from. I want to keep this data but obviously it makes more sense to store things like Agents in their own table and then keep an ID in the form data table. So I have an Agents class like this:

```
class Agent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'agents'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    ID = Column(Integer, autoincrement = True, primary_key = True)
    UserAgent = Column(VARCHAR(256), nullable = False, unique = True)

    #UniqueConstraint('UserAgent')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Agent(UserAgent='%s')>" % (self.UserAgent)
```

Then I have a form data class:

```
class Lead(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'leads'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}

    ID = Column(String(32), primary_key = True)
    AgentID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('agents.ID'), nullable = False)
    .... other non relational fields ....
    IsPartial = Column(Boolean, nullable = False)

    Agent = relationship('Agent', backref = backref('leads', uselist = True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Lead(ID='%s')>" % (self.ID)
```

At this point, SQLAlchemy creates all the tables I ask it to and I can create a test Lead instance:

```
testLead = Lead(ID='....', ...)
```

and then create a test Agent instance:

```
testAgent = Agent(UserAgent='...', leads=testLead)
```

The testLead instantiates just fine. However, the Agent instantiation fails with:

```
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Lead is not list-like
```

And using testLead.Agent = [...] results in:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to instantiate the Lead object with the Agent string. Then when I use session.add and session.commit have the ORM add the Agent string to the agents table if missing. Likewise when I instantiate the Lead class I'd like to be able to do it with:

```
lead = Lead(ID='...')
```

Then if I use:

```
lead.Agent
```

The agent string should show up. If I've read the docs right this would require some for of Lazy Loading setting being added.

Is there a way to do this? If not, how do I fix the errors above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the two sides of the `1-many` relationship: your code with test data works as if one `Lead` had many `Agents`, while the `relationship` definition is the opposite. Assuming the model is correct, the below should work:

```
testLead = Lead(ID='....', ...)
testAgent = Agent(UserAgent='...', leads=[testLead])
```

or:

```
testAgent = Agent(UserAgent='...')
testLead = Lead(ID='....', ..., Agent=testAgent)
```

As for the second part of your question, you can achieve it with simple python:

```
class Lead(Base):
    # ...

    @property
    def UserAgent(self):
        return self.Agent and self.Agent.UserAgent

    @UserAgent.setter
    def UserAgent(self, value):
        # @note: you might first want to search for agent with this UserAgent value, 
        # and create a new one only if one does not exist
        # agent_obj = object_session(self).query(Agent).filter(Agent.UserAgent == value).one()
        agent_obj = Agent(UserAgent=value)
        self.Agent = agent_obj

    @UserAgent.deleter
    def UserAgent(self):
        self.Agent = None
```

Or you can use [`Association Proxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) for the purpose:

```
def _agent_find_or_create(user_agent):
    agent = session.query(Agent).filter(Agent.UserAgent==user_agent).first()
    return agent or Agent(UserAgent=user_agent)

class Lead(Base):
    # ...

    Agent = relationship('Agent', backref = backref('leads', uselist = True))
    UserAgent = association_proxy('Agent', 'UserAgent',
                                  creator=_agent_find_or_create)
```

Comment: Many leads could have the same User Agent but a single lead should only have 1 User Agent. I thought the purpose of the relationships in SQLAlchemy's ORM was to handle all this. However, I see what you are doing now. I was trying to set Agent with a string when it needed to be an instance of Agent per my relationship. As you were putting in your answer I was getting the classes to insert data but then ran into an error where the Lead, thru a relationship, was attempting to re-insert a value on a UNIQUE column. So now I'm off to figure out how to do INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: Your 2nd code with testAgent set is the correct way for my purposes. I like the setter and deleter but I have a lot of properties to create setters and deleter attributes for so I may look for something more generic. Thanks

Comment: see update with association proxy, which also has the `find_or_create` routine (kind of INSERT IGNORE).

Comment: That association_proxy code worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: So your solution works great so long as I only have 2 associations/relationships. As soon as I add a 3rd the loop I'm using for entering the data in to the DB bombs. It always gives me an IntegrityError for one of the items being NULL that isn't allowed to be NULL. But it happens because the session.query from your find_and_create throws an error. SQLAlchemy then catches it and returns to the rest of the script where it then attempted to do the INSERT with most of the data missing. Oddly, everything works fine when I only have 2 associations/relationships but I have 12 so ...

Comment: Post a *minimal* non-working solution with 3 tables (on gist or so) and seek help. Otherwise this is too abstract. I do not see a reason why many relationships should not work.